# hyperlink is embedding unwanted keyword 'Servlet'

Tags: visualforce, formula-field, urlhacking

We have a below hyperlink formula field. the intent is to display clones as a list in custom object and when we click on cloned id it should bring the detail page for the clones record.

HYPERLINK(Id ,"PA history View")

But When we click the id it shows webaddress with servlet in between.

so for example:
instead of bringing https://salesforce.com/3292302442

it brings up
https://salesforce.com/servlet/3292302442

how to get rid of keyword servlet?

BTW: WE are using sandbox for this and tried ie and chrome but both have same results.

Here is Page Block inside Visual force page:

---

```
<apex:pageBlock title="PA History">
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Records}" var="Record"> 
        <apex:column > 
            <apex:facet name="header">PA#</apex:facet> 
            <apex:outputLink value="{!Record.PALink__c}">{!Record.id}</apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column> 
        <apex:column >
          <apex:outputLink value="{!Record.id}">{!Record.id}</apex:outputLink>
     </apex:column>

        <apex:column > 
            <apex:facet name="header">PA Trigger</apex:facet> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!Record.Trigger_Events__c}"/> 
        </apex:column> 
        <apex:column > 
            <apex:facet name="header">Revision #</apex:facet> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!Record.PA_Rev_No__c}"/> 
        </apex:column> 

    </apex:pageBlockTable> 
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Here is the answer to my problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552514/visualforce-page-embedded-in-a-detail-page-that-needs-to-redirect-to-other-page

Comment: Here is the resource I feel like worth sharing:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552514/visualforce-page-embedded-in-a-detail-page-that-needs-to-redirect-to-other-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a forward slash. Try:

```
HYPERLINK("/" & Id, "PA history View")
```

This will output HTML similar to what is below, with a relative URL to the object you want.

```
<a href="/a0Kd000000GBStn" target="_blank">PA history View</a>
```

Bare in mind that this formula field is now a hyperlink (i.e. the output is what is shown above), it is not just a URl. If you are using this field in a visualforce page then you don't need to use a [apex:outputLink](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputLink.htm) tag as it is already a hyperlink. You could display it using an [apex:outputText](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm) but with escape set to false so that it displays correctly.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Record.PALink__c}" escape="false"/>
```

Or if you wanted to not use a formula field at all you could do it all in the VF page:

```
<apex:outputLink value="/{!Record.Id}">PA history View</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: I tried it before but the same thing, even we tried adding id as <apex:outputLink> but servlet keyword is keep coming. This is what we tried in visual force page:      <apex:outputLink value="{!Record.id}">{!Record.id}</apex:outputLink>

Comment: Is this formula being used directly in VisualForce or is it being used in a formula field?

Comment: BarCotter this formula is being used in formula field.

Comment: What type of formula field? Is it a Text formula?

Comment: yes it is a text formula field.

Comment: I just tested this out in an org and I got the correct URL. I have updated my answer to include the outputted HTML.

Comment: Hi BarCotter, You are right this field is working fine in standard page but since we added this field in a visual force page which in turn is added into standard page layout.  I believe this is due to fact that we are using it in visual force page. Any work around on how to get rid of 'servlet' keyword if hyperlink formula field is accessed inside Visual force page.

Comment: Please update your question to include the visualforce that you are using to display the URL